# Is the preposition "of" ever OK after numbers and units of measurement?

Tags: prepositions

Would it be correct to say "5 billion cubic meters OF natural gas". Is the preposition "of" ever OK after numbers and units of measurement?

Comment: Yes perfectly idiomatic. *There were ten of them present at the meeting*.

Comment: Hi Irina, Welcome to EL&U. This seems like a very basic question. Although it's fine to ask it here but it might be better if you consider our sister site(http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for such questions in future. That site is targeted for people who have started to learn English and the users there are by default considered as non-native speakers, so the chances of entertaining this question would be more there!

Answer (score 3):

Yes - when it is presenting a quantity or portion of a resource: usually volume or mass, but it can also be used with other dimensions, eg *half an hour of your time*, or *an acre of land*, or *ten yards of that cloth please*.